# Has anybody run Xvfb on EC2 with CentOS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cucumber, centos, xvfb

I am trying to get javascript-enabled cucumber running on CentOS in EC2 by following this tutorial: http://makandra.com/notes/1391-how-to-hide-your-selenium-browser-window-with-headless However, the scenarios that require javascript just fail without any exception message.

In order to debug, I just went to see if Xvfb is working correctly with according to this tutorial: http://blog.kabisa.nl/2010/05/24/headless-cucumbers-and-capybaras-with-selenium-and-hudson/

I tested the command:

```
Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x16
```

I got the error msg like this:

```
_XSERVTransSocketOpenCOTSServer: Unable to open socket for inet6
_XSERVTransOpen: transport open failed for inet6/ip-10-116-82-44:99
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: failed to open listener for inet6
```

I googled for solutions about of these errors. I haven't found a good solution for this yet. If I run the same command again, I get:

```
Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 99
    If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X99-lock
    and start again.
```

So the server is supposed to be up and running already. However, when I tried to run this in followups:

```
DISPLAY=:99.0 firefox http://www.google.com
```

The console just hangs there, until I contol + C to kill it.
Is there anyone who knows what's going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that it's okay. Your console didn't hang - it is firefox is working - you just don't see it:)

Edit: I think you can connect there with ssh -X and you'll see firefox window if it is working. (Only if you're running linux/mac on your dev machine)